# Pasar parametros usando Html.BeginForm FormMethod.Get

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y uso el siguiente metodo [BeginForm](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-html-formextensions-beginform(system-web-mvc-htmlhelper-system-string-system-string-system-object-system-web-mvc-formmethod))

Mi problema es que en el controlador por medio de la solicitud `[HttpGet]` lo que envio por parametro no llega, pero cuando lo hago por `[HttpPost]` Si llega.

Quiero saber porque ocurre esto, me interesa que funcione por `[HttpGet]`.

Anexo codigo del Form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActualizarId", "Cliente", new { idCliente = Model.Id }, FormMethod.Get ))
{
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <button class="btn form-control" type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Anexo codigo del Controller

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult ActualizarId(int idCliente = 0)
 {

 }
```

No entiendo porque cuando cambio mi controller y mi formulario a `POST` si llega, pero por `GET` no lo hace

Answer (score 0):

con relación a tu consulta, es importante tener en cuenta los distintos verbos Http, cada uno de ellos tienen una funcionalidad y forma de enviar los datos.

[Verbos HTTP](https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/rails-verbos-http)

Cuando envías una solicitud al servidor para actualizar un registro, lo correcto es utilizar el metodo **POST**, ya que estarás enviando información, el metodo **GET** te servirá cuando desees enviar información a la vista o bien, desees desplegar una vista.

Esto es importante cuando trabajes con estos metodos tener esto en cuenta.

Nota: Al querer enviar la información dentro de un get deberás enviar los parametros por medio de queryStrings o bien, especificarle al controlador por donde va a recibir la información **[FromBody]** **[FromForm]** etc. sin embargo, te recomiendo utilizarlo con POST ya que es más seguro para el envío de datos.

Espero te haya servido.

Saludos.